# Filter by column qualifier using hive

Tags: hbase, hive

I'm saving documents that registered users have read. I'm using the following model:

object:day as key

users as column family

timestamp: as column qualifier

user_id: as column value

I'd like to filter by **timestamp** or **user_id** ranges, is it possible using hive?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood it correctly you want a **select * from table where user_id>=start_range and user_id<=end_range;**. Let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, but the key is I don't have one a known schema. I'm using the Hbase principle: billion of rows and million of columns.

But it seams that there's no tool that accomplishes with this model

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can't map this type of table to hive since it you add new columns (per timestamp) and hive requires a known schema when you CREATE the table